# android menu like facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I wanna make android menu that appears from left to right like facebook app menu
what is the name of this component or how?

This is the image of facebook menu
http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/7627/img20130223153440.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First: What is it with you and exclamation marks? Or has your cat decided to take a nap on the Shift and 1 key? ;)

Second: Use this android library for these kind of menus: 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

It works very well and is used by many "famous" apps (see the link for more information).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries out there that can do it. The best one I've found is [MenuDrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) from SimonVT and Jake Wharton. It's pretty easy and powerful. It also uses hardware layers so it doesn't create overdraw by having the menu drawn underneath the layout.